# Getting specific rows in a Powershell variable/array

Tags: sql, arrays, powershell, rows

I hope I'm able to ask my question as simple as possible. I am very new to working with PowerShell.

Now to my question:

I use `Invoke-Sqlcmd` to run a query, which puts Data in a variable, let's say `$Data`.

In this case I query for triggers in an SQL Database.

Then I kind of split the array to get more specific information:

```
$Data2 = $Data | Where {$_.table -like 'dbo.sportswear'}
$Data3 = $Data2 | Where {$_.event -match "Delete"}
```

So in the end I have a variable with these Indexes(?), I'm not sure if they are called indexes.

```
table
trigger_name
activation
event
type
status
definition
```

Now all I want is to check something in the `definition`.
So I create a `$Data4 = $Data3.definition`, so far so good.

But now I have a big text and I want only the content of 2-3 specific rows.
When I used like `$Data4[1]` or `$Data4[1..100]`, I realized that PowerShell sees every char as a line/row.

But when I just write `$Data4` it shows me the content nice formatted with paragraphs, new lines and so on.

Has anyone an idea how I can get specific rows or lines of my variable?

Thank you all :)

Comment: You could try `($Data4 -split '\r?\n')[1..3]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears `$Data4` is a formatted string. Since it is a single string, any indexed element lookups return single characters (of type `System.Char`). If you want indexes to return longer substrings, you will need to split your string into multiple strings somehow or come up with a more sophisticated search mechanism.

If we assume the rows you are after are actual lines separated by line feed and/or carriage return, you can just split on those newline characters and use indexes to access your lines:

```
# Array indexing starts at 0 for line 1. So [1] is line 2.
# Outputs lines 2,3,4
($Data4 -split '\r?\n')[1..3]

# Outputs lines 2,7,20
($Data4 -split '\r?\n')[1,6,19]
```

`-split` uses regex to match characters and perform a string split on all matches. It results in an array of substrings. `\r` matches a carriage return. `\n` matches a line feed. `?` matches 0 or one character, which is needed in case there are no carriage returns preceding your line feeds.

Comment: Well, <3 that's a really big help for me :). Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @Daeny, if this answer provides what you need, please consider selecting the checkmark to make it an official answer.